# Disabling -Werror for -Wimplicit-interface

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, fortran, compiler-warnings, gfortran

What is the right flag or order of flags to disable treating particular warning as error in GCC? I want to do that for `-Wimplicit-interface`.

```
>cat test.f90 
 call s
end

> gfortran -c -Werror -Wimplicit-interface -Wno-error=implicit-interface test.f90 -o test.o
test.f90:1.7:

 call s
       1
Warning: Procedure 's' called with an implicit interface at (1)

>ls test*
test.f90
```

No `test.o` was generated.

Without `-Werror` it works

```
> gfortran -c -Wimplicit-interface -Wno-error=implicit-interface test.f90 -o test.o
test.f90:1.7:

 call s
       1
Warning: Procedure 's' called with an implicit interface at (1)
> ls test*
test.f90  test.o
```

GCC version is `gcc version 4.9.2 20141030 (Cray Inc.) (GCC)`.

Comment: That seems to work as you expect with gcc-5.

Comment: Interesting, that might be the answer to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @innoSPG points out, the actual behaviour does not conform to what is claimed in the manual.

The comment by @MarkGlisse revealed that this have changed with GCC 5. Therefore it was probably a bug.

The solution is therefore to use the recent version, or to not use one of the `-Werror` and `-Wimplicit-interface`.

Or to really provide explicit interfaces everywhere, but that can be problematic, as MPI libraries differ in the amount of explicit interfaces provided in the `mpi` modules.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an explicit answer to the question. I found it educative enough and too long to be put as comment.

As you just found, you might not be able to achieve what you want if you combine `-Werror` and `-Wno-error=implicit-interface`. Let me explain: as opposed to what we have in the [doc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options), especially the following sentence,

> The combined effect of positive and negative forms is that more specific options have priority over less specific ones, independently of their position in the command-line.

It seems that it is not the case in the actual implementation. I had a similar problem recently, and by googling, I found [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2015-10/msg00016.html) which contains this sentence:

> '-w' permanently sets all warnings off no matter what specific warning is set on

It actually suggests that by using some non specific options, the actual implementation does not allow you to change specific option included in the non specific one.